# How does one implement a FlinkKafkaPartitioner?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm working on developing a Flink Service where I read messages from one Kafka, then de-serialize them to HashMap and do some things with them and finally write them to another Kafka. Now I've run into a problem that I do not know how to solve and I've found no examples online on how to solve it. 
What I'm trying to do is to create a custom partition for my Flink Kafka Producer so that events with the same id go to the same partition since it's important to keep events from the same id in order. However I do not understand how to implement the FlinkKafkaPartitioner and the docs are less than helpful in that regard.

What I've got so far for Producer is the following(using null for FlinkKafkaProducer since I just wanted to get it working but this should be replaced by the custom partitioner):

```
FlinkKafkaProducer010<String> writeToNewPipe = new FlinkKafkaProducer010<String>(
                processorConfig.getKafkaDestTopic(),
                new SimpleStringSchema(),
                producerProps,
                (FlinkKafkaPartitioner) null
        );
```

And in my code I do the following:

```
eventsFromOldPipe
                .map(event -> {
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
                    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
                    try {
                        return mapper.writeValueAsString(event);
                    }
                    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .addSink(writeToNewPipe);
```

where *eventsFromOldPipe* emits HashMap.

Now say that the HashMap from *eventsFromOldPipe* contains a sessionId field that I'd like to use for the partition key, and ideally I'd also like to remove that sessionId from the record that is sent by the producer to Kafka if at all possible (it's not critical that it's removed but would be nice).

I'm quite new to the more "custom" parts of Flink implementations so I'm severely lost in this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you checked kafka mirror maker? the official tool aims to move data from one kafka to the other kafka. You can transform the data in the source kafka first using flink, and then mirror the transformed data from source kafka to target kafka, which takes much less effort that no custom flink kafka producer is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just implement KafkaSerializationSchema,define ProducerRecord with key and value.
kafka will partition the records by what key you defined.